# How to return only one triangle from the set of isomorphic triangles?

Tags: r, igraph, isomorphism

The original question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328929/probability-that-graph-with-6-vertices-and-5-edges-has-a-triangle/3329441?noredirect=1#comment6852795_3329441).

> How to calcultate a probability that a graph with 6 vertices and 5
>   edges has a triangle?

I would like to make a simulation. I going to create the `triangle` graph then generate the `1,000` random graphs with `n=6` vertecies and `m=5` edges, and find the distibutions of triangles.

Now I created a `g` graph with one triangle, the `subgraph_isomorphisms()` function returns `6` isomorphic triangles.
Then I used the `unique()` function in order to find one triangle.
But the result is `6`.

```
library(igraph) 

g          <- graph_from_literal( A--B, B--C, C--A, B--D, D--E, E--F)
triangle   <- graph_from_literal( A--B, B--C, C--A) 

ntriangles <- 0

iso <- subgraph_isomorphisms(triangle, g) 

motifs <- lapply(iso, function (x) { induced_subgraph(g, x) }) 
ntriangles <- length(unique(motifs))  
ntriangles
```

**Question.** 
How to return only one triangle from the set of isomorphic triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to aggregate the edgelist of each motif into a data.frame and use `dplyr`'s `distinct` to filter the unique values:

```
library(dplyr)
edgelist <- do.call(rbind,
                    lapply(1:length(motifs), function(x) get.edgelist(motifs[[x]])))
edgelist <- data.frame(edgelist) %>% distinct() %>% as.matrix()
graph_from_edgelist(edgelist, directed = F)
```

This returns:

```
> graph_from_edgelist(edgelist, directed = F)
IGRAPH e275587 UN-- 3 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from e275587 (vertex names):
[1] A--B A--C B--C
```

---

**EDIT**   Here is another approach, which is shorter and closer to the one OP proposed:

```
motifs <- lapply(iso, function (x) { get.edgelist(induced_subgraph(g, x)) })   
ntriangles <- length(unique(motifs))  
ntriangles
```

Here I simply extract the edgelist, which contains the vertices. Without the unique `graph_id` and the other information stored in the igraph-object, `unique` will return the following:

```
> length(unique(motifs))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. What is problem in my code? The different indexation of vertexes in g and triangle graphs?

Comment: `induced_subgraph` will return all the vertices specified in the `v` argument. This means that your code queries 6 different combinations of A,B,C and returns the subgraph of their forms. This results in 6 different `?graph_id`'s, and that's why `unique` classifies them all as unique.